# Helm3 - Reading json file into configmap produces a string?

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

**Problem:**

I want to read a json file into a configmap so it looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: json-test
data:
  test.json: |-
    {
      "key": "val"
    }
```

Instead I get

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: json-test
data:
  test.json: |-
      "{\r\n    \"key\": \"val\"\r\n}"
```

**What I've done:**

I have the following helm chart:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2020-02-06  10:51 AM                static
d-----        2020-02-06  10:55 AM                templates
-a----        2020-02-06  10:51 AM             88 Chart.yaml
```

static/ contains a single file: `test.json`:

```
{
    "key": "val"
}
```

templates/ contains a single configmap that reads test.json: `test.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: json-test
data:
  test.json: |-
  {{ toJson ( .Files.Get "static/test.json" ) | indent 4}}
```

When I run `helm install test . --dry-run --debug` I get the following output

```
NAME: test
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Feb  6 10:58:18 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: pending-install
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
{}

COMPUTED VALUES:
{}

HOOKS:
MANIFEST:
---
# Source: sandbox/templates/test.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: json-test
data:
  test.json: |-
      "{\r\n    \"key\": \"val\"\r\n}"
```

The problem here is my json is wrapped in double quotes. My process that wants to read the json is expecting actual json, not a string.

Comment: have you tried only with {{ .Files.Get "static/test.json" | indent 4}} .. try remove toJson is you already have a valid json in path .... may be do a  jsonlint on  test.json if you are not sure. !!

Comment: I have tired, but I get syntax errors on the first `{` 

`Error: YAML parse error on sandbox/templates/test.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: did not find expected key
helm.go:76: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 8: did not find expected key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that this is not specific behavior only for **helm 3**. It generally works in **kubernetes** this way.

I've just tested it on **kubernetes v1.13**.

First I created a `ConfigMap` based on this file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: json-test
data:
  test.json: |-
    {   
      "key": "val"
    }
```

When I run:

```
$ kubectl get configmaps json-test -o yaml
```

I get the expected output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  test.json: |-
    {
      "key": "val"
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
...
```

but when I created my `ConfigMap` based on json file with the following content:

```
{   
      "key": "val"
}
```

by running:

```
$ kubectl create configmap json-configmap --from-file=test-json.json
```

Then when I run:

```
kubectl get cm json-configmap --output yaml
```

I get:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  test-json.json: "    {   \n      \"key\": \"val\"\n    } \n"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
...
```

So it looks like it's pretty normal for kubernetes to transform the original **json format** into **string** when a `ConfigMap` is created from file.

It doesn't seem to be a bug as kubectl doesn't have any problems with extracting properly formatted json format from such `ConfigMap`:

```
kubectl get cm json-configmap -o jsonpath='{.data.test-json\.json}'
```

gives the correct output:

```
{   
  "key": "val"
}
```

I would say that it is application responsibility to be able to extract **json** from such **string** and it can be done probably in many different ways e.g. making direct call to `kube-api` or using `serviceaccount` configured to use `kubectl` in `Pod`.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the samed problem with the format, also when creating the configmap from a yaml file. The fix for me was to remove all trailing whitspace.